Why little endian? (Regarding shifts)
I'm a programmer, wondering about the impact of byte ordering on bit shift operations.
I've come back around to this topic time and time again but never found an answer to it:
Why does everyone hype the little endian representation so much?
Big endian notation is explained across the internet to mean that the bytes, and only the bytes, of multi byte numbers are reordered in memory from e.g. this: 0x01234567 to this: 0x67452301.
Which is neither efficiently readable forwards nor backwards.
It also makes impractical bit shifting, because 'shifting the bits left' in a high level language, making the number larger, for any number larger than 1 byte, now means every 8th bit starting at the first needs to be shifted 15 bit to the right instead, introducing one hell of a hot mess.
Why is every hardware manufacturer so obsessed with this nonsense? Why was it made a standard? What am I missing? Is the bit order reversed and all the explainer vids got it wrong?
Please send help.
I tried googling for an answer, and found no expert giving a solid answer to this.

All bit shift operations happen in the CPU registers, where the bytes of the value are in the correct order. The reasons for this design go back to the early 4 bit and 8 bit chips. Try the manufacturers' websites for full descriptions of their design.

"from e.g. this: 0x01234567 to this: 0x67452301" That's little endian you describe. In big endian, the number 0x01234567 is stored as 01,23,45,67.
